# функция "void lve::FirstApp::run(void)" уже имеет текст реализации

Tags: c++, opengl, vulkan

first_app.cpp

```
#include "first_app.hpp"

namespace lve {

    void FirstApp::run() {
        while (!lveWindow.shouldClose()) {
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

first_app.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include "lve_window.hpp"

namespace lve {
    class FirstApp {
    public:
        static constexpr int WIDTH = 800;
        static constexpr int HEIGHT = 600;

        void run();
        
    private:
        LveWindow lveWindow{ WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Hello Vulkan!" };
    };
}
```

Comment: Например, если вместо `#include "first_app.hpp"` где-то использовано `#include "first_app.cpp"`...